# Find u as function of x and y using Python Sympy module when u is given in 2 equations

Tags: python, math, sympy, solver

My goal is to find u as function of x and y using Sympy module.
the equations are:

1. [image: for x]
2. [image: for y]

The answer should be:

[image: Ans]

```
from sympy import cosh, sinh, symbols, sin, cos, Eq
u, v, x, y = symbols('u, v, x, y')
eqq1 = Eq(x, sin(u)*cosh(v))
eqq2 = Eq(y, cos(u)*sinh(v))
```

What's next?

I tried

```
result = solve((Eqq1, Eqq2), u, v)
```

Obviously it's not the right way.

Comment: Note: I am unable to read the equations using dark mode for stack overflow. I think the background of your image is transparent. You should make it solid instead.

Comment: Why is it obviously not the right way? The code  looks reasonable to me. What is the problem?

Comment: hey @mkrieger1 thank you for your question.
This is not the right way. currently you have x and y as function of u and v. x(u,v) y(u,v)
If you solve the equation as I mentioned before, you will solve the 2 equations separately like they were independent, and not take in account the relation between those two equations.
moreover if you do so you wont be able to find U as function of x and y

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer that you expect, but you can rework the problem by eliminating `v`, as follows:

```
(x cos u)² - (y sin u)² = cos²u sin²u
```

Then with `t = sin²u`, the equation is quadratic in `t`:

```
x² (1 - t) - y² t = (1 - t) t
```

Comment: How did you get to the first equation? how did you eliminate v?
I still think there is a way to solve that in sympy without any further math

Comment: @Morten: plug x and y in it.

Answer (score 0):

Divide each side of x equation by cosh(v) and each side of y equation by sinh(v). Square all sides. Replace `sinh(v)**2` with z and `cosh(v)**2` with 1 + z. The sum of the lhs of the equations is 1. The difference is cos(2u). You can solve for cos(2u) and z and work out something close to what you are looking for.

```py
>>> from sympy import x, y, z, v, u
>>> from sympy import cosh,sinh,cos,Tuple,solve
>>> e1 = x**2/cosh(v)**2 + y**2/sinh(v)**2-1
>>> e2 = y**2/sinh(v)**2-x**2/cosh(v)**2-cos(2*u)
>>> solve(Tuple(e1,e2).subs(cosh(v)**2,1+z).subs(sinh(v)**2,z), z, cos(2*u), dict=True)
[
{z: x**2/2 + y**2/2 - sqrt((x**2 - 2*x + y**2 + 1)*(x**2 + 2*x + y**2 + 1))/2 - 1/2, 
cos(2*u): -x**2 - y**2 - sqrt((x**2 - 2*x + y**2 + 1)*(x**2 + 2*x + y**2 + 1))}, 

{z: x**2/2 + y**2/2 + sqrt((x**2 - 2*x + y**2 + 1)*(x**2 + 2*x + y**2 + 1))/2 - 1/2, 
cos(2*u): -x**2 - y**2 + sqrt((x**2 - 2*x + y**2 + 1)*(x**2 + 2*x + y**2 + 1))}]
```

Comment: hey @peter, I tried to define new equation as you mentioned, it seems that sympy still cant solve it.
[picture](https://imgur.com/a/NCYK7cI)